# Weird Issue accessing properties in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm probably being stupid, but:

```
@activation_token = ActivationToken.where(:token => params[:id])
render(:text => @activation_token.inspect)
```

Works, and gives:

```
[#<ActivationToken id: 7, user_id: 21, token: "f4c3cb7c7629344e8261bf16e4a99900", used: false, created_at: "2013-01-25 10:48:57", updated_at: "2013-01-25 10:48:57">]
```

But

```
@activation_token.user_id
```

Throws:

```
undefined method `user_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fbfe414ff18>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@activation_token.first.user_id
```

It is giving collection of objects, if you want to access @activation_token.user_id, Use:

```
@activation_token = ActivationToken.where(:token => params[:id]).first
# or
@activation_token = ActivationToken.find_by_token(params[:id])
```